How to blur the background of an image or video dynamically according to the image or video displayed in flutter
Basically, the background gradient should change and blend according to the content being displayed with a blurry effect just like YouTube and Instagram does

I tried to stack two images but it didn't appear like this. So I'm curious whether there's a more efficient way to approach.

You can gather the dominant color of an image using palette_generator package.
The following example will be applied on an image.
Here's widget structure:
class ImageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                fit: StackFit.expand,
                children: [
                  FutureBuilder(
                      future: _updatePaletteGenerator(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [
                                snapshot.data!.dominantColor!.color,
                                Colors.white
                              ],
                              begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              end: Alignment.topCenter,
                            )),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Text('Waiting');
                        }
                      }),
                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Image.network(
                          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/02/25/10/11/forsythia-8595521_1280.jpg'))
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}

Here's how this package is used:
Future<PaletteGenerator> _updatePaletteGenerator() async {
  var paletteGenerator = await PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(
    Image.network(
            'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/02/25/10/11/forsythia-8595521_1280.jpg')
        .image,
  );
  return paletteGenerator;
}

In the above example i give the PaletteGenerator the image which is displayed in the widget.
result for different images:


For more info see palette_generator_example

This actually worked perfectly for images. Thank you. Is there a way to do for same for videos?
